# No internet connection on ubuntu desktop 20.04 lts

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet

I've just bought a new wifi router, now i'm trying to connect it with my ubuntu pc... Ubuntu is connecting my pc to the router but says no internet connection. The same router works fine with windows 10, android 9, 11, & 8.

I'm trying to figure out the problem, i've checked changing my ip address in router, tried changing static ip address in my ubuntu (manually).

It still doesn't works, all the drivers are fully updated.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you managed to connect your Ubuntu system to any other wifi/router in the past?  is this a new problem, or has your internet never worked?

Comment: @Jad I was previously using my mobile's data connection via wifi tethering it works fine...Although, I've fixed this issue.

Comment: Do you want to update the question with an answer, if you've fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with was my ubuntu, it wasn't identifying DNS correctly, in my case, I wanted specifically use `43` in my dns. For example, `192.168.43.1`.

---

To check your required dns address:

*this option **might** work, I haven't tested in this way...*

connect to another network which works with your ubuntu, type `ifconfig` in terminal, see your address and replace the `43` with yours.